# I find ore but as I destroy it, it doesn't drop. Why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built my own mine and found gold and diamonds, but no matter what I used to destroy them, they just disappeared. I didn't get anything at all.

Why is this?

Comment: What kind of tools are you using?

Comment: Sounds like creative mode.